# redux way of rendering data not successful in my sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to show the data in redux way.
- **when you click advanced sports search button a drawer opens up in that when you click search attributes it should render history data**
- so I created this method in the actions fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL
- and then called this fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL method in the tabs of the drawer.
- but its not displaying the data.
- I debugged and found undefined for this  const historySports = this.props.historySports;
  console.log("historySports--->", historySports);
- I am using mapDispatchToProps but still I am not successful.
- I am trying to display my data here             reading the data from api{historySports}
- all my render code is in this file sports-advanced-search.js
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

**actions**

```
export const fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL = data => {
  return dispatch => {
    if (data != undefined) {
      return axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
        data: data,
        config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
      })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log("fetchSportsHistoryData--->", response);
          dispatch(fetchSportsHistoryData(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
          dispatch(fetchSportsHistoryData([]));
        });
    }
  };
};
```

**render code**

```
  getHistoryData = values => {
    this.props.fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL();
  };


   render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    const Sports = this.props.Sports;
    const historySports = this.props.historySports;
    console.log("historySports--->", historySports);
    console.log("this.props--->", this.props);
    console.log("this.state--->", this.state);
   }
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL: () => {
      dispatch(fetchHistorySportsDatafromURL());
    }
  };
};

export default withStyles(styles)(
  connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(ScrollableTabsButtonAuto)
);
```

Comment: I don't see you defining historySports on props anywhere.  Are they passed in from somewhere?

Comment: @jmargolisvt hey I am confused do I need to update  like this in the state --->     historySports: {},  I updated the code, I went through so many tutorials but still its confusing....can you directly  update my sandbox and give comments so that I can learn https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.  Without fixing them for you, here's what I think is confusing you...

1. State and props are two different things.  You can use Redux to `mapStateToProps` for easy use in your component.  You may want to do that once you successfully update the Redux state.
2. Redux state and component-level state are also two different things.  The `this.state` that is defined in the constructor is that component's state.  You can can't just add another `state` object and expect `setState` to update it.  Your state object is not bound to the class.
3. To update the Redux state, your idea to `dispatch(fetchSportsHistoryData(response.data)` from the response is on the right track.  Now you need for that action to return the data to the state.  You need to make sure you have a reducer listening for `FETCH_HISTORY_Sports`, which responds by updating the Redux state.
4. Now if you have that part together, you can now use `mapStateToProps` in your component and then you can access it with `this.props.historySports`.

Comment: hey thanks so much it helped me to understand the concepts with practical example...I created reducer for FETCH_HISTORY_Sports but still I am not able to show the data...can you give some more inputs so that I can fix it...providing my updated sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

Comment: You aren't passing the same message.  `FETCH_HISTORY_Sports` vs `FETCH_HISTORY_SPORTS`

Comment: @jmargolistv hey I updated the code but still I am not able to fix the issue...can you help me...I updated the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp